# OAuth2 Authentication server access token form JWT token to OAuth Token

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt

Is it possible the changes the token form JWT token to OAuth2 token.

Sample code from Daily Code BUffer https://github.com/shabbirdwd53/spring-security-tutorial/blob/main/Oauth-authorization-server/src/main/java/com/dailycodebuffer/oauthserver/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
 @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }
```

/oauth2/token endpoint

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiI3MzA5MmI1Yy00MDc0LTRkZjktOTdhNS1kMzA3N2E4NDNhYzciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJhdWQiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJuYmYiOjE2NjY2NzgyNTYsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiXSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDAiLCJleHAiOjE2NjY2NzkxNTYsImlhdCI6MTY2NjY3ODI1Nn0.QJOMrp2unqLP-nGYo5lnlg1Q3_XXR2XZBTQqt3C9tkhiVs4I2dDjaWze1LrnjEnP2hfb89XqpT1k1AjR_ApsOx5H8PcqqZ0Eaq89ICX6bu3LFo2HApYlV5kRQTD3HQq0uiA_hn9TTdvBJhM5Kz9_0rPQVzBpNqWGnkWzGvbukRPgnBYLNi6lVwOG3mZxkP8aNiOn5Z5PMo9pll6idQLadJtFQ7fKTjG8mFqh1BtLwpmH4U60dzaieafCXwczywKq0xVzk9asB9c0-gw_BbeK4Vns3tp8AzCCyH4rRwy6ssVblUlycyss7scpY9s2ibUZ6N3xg97nowp9Ygqjv_bccw",
    "scope": "read",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 899
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that JWTs are not OAuth(2)?

Comment: @ch4mp i just check now the token at https://jwt.io/ contains no type, but im not sure if its Jwt token since it contain header.payload.verify signature. i been watching some tutorial that their access token is short which is short unlike what i receive is too long and contain like a JWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oauth(2) standard makes no assumption on the token format. Authorization-server can use absolutely what he wants to.

If authorization-server issues JWT tokens, then other OAuth2 actors can decode and validate tokens with no more than authorization-server public key.

Other token formats, are considered "opaque" and must be introspected on the authorization-server for validation and to get associated claims.